# How to handle with Out-dated posts?

Tags: discussion

This question is mostly related to programming. Such as EJB vs Spring. Many popular answers I found @SO has been written in 2009/2010. But in these 5 years, many innovations, many alternatives, many solutions.

How do a SO user can find that answer is updated? Only just with the edited date. Ok Fine.

Many answers are not updated/it may remain same. How do a user find that is right answer[according to current technologies]?

What can SO do for this problem?

Comment: Can you show some examples where there are only out-of-date answers? I'm open to the possibility that there is a problem here, but so far, no one asking the question has been able to provide a meaningful sample of real-world questions to look at.

Comment: My question has raised based on the update part of highest voted answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779169/spring-vs-ejb-can-spring-replace-ejb). Then I got a doubt whether I learned right answers so far. That's why I mentioned most of the popular votes are created in 2009&2010. I am not saying all questions has this problem. Only some may have. In the mentioned question user has added updates due to the comments.

Comment: That's not a bad example. It has the added obstacle of being closed, so no one could provide a new answer even if they wanted. Hmmmm